# How can I use implode to query the database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I built an array of strings and I'm attempting to query mySQL table.  I want to find all rows that match my list of items separated with the word 'AND'.  I've tried the code below but got no result back.  How can I improve my code to perform the proper query using implode?

Thanks for any help.

```
 $conditions = array(
     'Monday',
     'Tuesday',
     'Wednesday'
 );
 $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
}

 $query = "SELECT * FROM match_tracker ";

 // append the conditions

 $query.= "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $conditions);
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

 if ($result)
{
echo "Results positive.  ";
}

 if (!$result)
{
echo "Empty results.";
die("database query failed.");
```

Comment: Going by your code, your SQL query should look like this: `"SELECT * FROM match_tracker WHERE Monday AND Tuesday AND Wednesday"`. Is that your intended sql string? If you wish to have something more meaningful, you'd have to go by way of associative arrays.

Comment: well your creating an invalid query, but the method should be changed to use `IN()`

Comment: Additionally you'd have to quote each value in the `implode()` in order for the query to work.

Comment: `IN` creates an `OR` @Dagon

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data? I am getting the feeling that @Dagon is more likely right where *you're* concerned. And please add some error checking to your MySQLi, there are things happening here that you're not aware of. There is no way that a single column value could be 'Monday' AND 'Tuesday' AND 'Wednesday' unless there is temporal misalignment I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your code, your SQL query should look like this: `"SELECT * FROM match_tracker WHERE Monday AND Tuesday AND Wednesday"`. Is that your intended sql string? If you wish to have something more meaningful, you'd have to go by way of associative arrays. Something like below would be more appropriate:

```
$conditions = array(
 'Monday' => '1',
 'Tuesday' => '4', 
 'Wednesday' => '3'
 );
 $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM match_tracker WHERE true";

// append the conditions

foreach($conditions AS $key => $value)
{
   $query .= "AND $key = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $value). "'";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result)
{
   echo "Results positive.  ";
}

else if (!$result)
{
   echo "Empty results.";
   die("database query failed.");
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: My values are quoted. And although hardcoded, I have also escaped them, just incase he needs to use the same code with data coming from user input

Comment: Both methods work but I like the associative array more.  I can do more with it.  Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the values in the `implode()` are quoted correctly:

```
$items = "day = '" . implode("' AND day = '", $conditions) . "'"; // day = 'Monday' AND day = 'Tuesday' AND day = 'Wednesday'
$query.= "WHERE " . $items;
```

The one thing you have forgotten above is a column to test against, such as the `day` column I have added in the `WHERE` condition.

If you're wanting to get data from the table where something occurred on a Monday, Tuesday OR Wednesday then you would do this:

```
$days = "('" . implode("', '", $conditions) . "')"; // ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday')
$query .= "WHERE day IN" . $days;
```